# Does operating system scheduler affect the way how threads are executed

Tags: vmware

I am coding a multi-thread application using the pthread library , I create a thread using pthread_create and run  `randomfunction` everything a thread is created

Psedo-code of application

```
pthread_t thread[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)

{
   pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, randomfunction, NULL)
}
```

For some unknown reason , the threads are not running concurrently but running one after the other , its like the pthread function has to execute finish before another pthread_create is executed .

I am wondering if its possible that the Ubuntu operating system Scheduler is affecting the way the threads are being executed .

Is it possible that the Ubuntu operating system Scheduler is causing the threads to run only when the calling function has finished executing rather than concurrently ???

I am running Ubuntu 9.10 on VMWare Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to set the number of processors to more than one in VirtualBox settings | System | Processor
2. You also need to set the BIOS to Virtualization (look under System Security settings).

That worked for me.